# Coroutine scope on Application class android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need a reference to coroutine scope on my android `Application`. i did the following

```
class TodoApplication : Application() {
    private var job = Job()
    private val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

    val tasksRepository: TasksRepository
        get() = ServiceLocator.provideTasksRepository(this, applicationScope)

}
```

Is this the way to do it. If so how can I cancel coroutines launched on this scope `job.cancel()`

Application class don't have onDestroy method as Activities

Comment: If you have an asynchronous worker whose lifecycle is truly global (they only die/end when your process dies), using GlobalScope or a similar life-long scope, is fine.

Comment: Dispatchers.Main cannot be used for background work. If you are updating that database or doing an API call, the recommendation is to use Dispatchers.IO. If it is just CPU background work, use Dispatchers.Default. Of course, you can redefine the scope with `withContext()` method or launch method.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

NO , **GlobalScope** will **NOT** be suitable for Application instance.

As mention here in this article [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-patterns-for-work-that-shouldnt-be-cancelled-e26c40f142ad):

---

**There are multiple reasons why you shouldn’t use GlobalScope:**

- **Promotes hard-coding values.**
  It might be tempting to hardcode `Dispatchers` if you use `GlobalScope` straight-away. That’s a bad practice!
- **It makes testing very hard.**
  As your code is going to be executed in an uncontrolled scope, you won’t be able to manage execution of work started by it.
- **You can’t have a common CoroutineContext for all coroutines**
  built into the scope as we did with the `applicationScope`. Instead, you’d have to pass a common `CoroutineContext` to all coroutines started by `GlobalScope`.

---

So, one solution for this is to create your own scope like this: <strike>`val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main)`</strike> **But better yet**, as pointed out by @Raman in the comments, use the equivalent that's already available to you:

```
kotlinx.coroutines.MainScope()
```

We don’t need to cancel this scope since we want it to remain active as long as
the application process is alive, so we don’t hold a reference to the SupervisorJob.
We can use this scope to run coroutines that need a longer lifetime than the calling
scope might offer in our app.

Comment: This exact scope is now available in the coroutines library as function `kotlinx.coroutines.MainScope()`

Comment: would this do all its work on the Main thread?

Comment: @hmac yes it would work on the Main thread. You can use `withContext` if you want to switch to other thread pools.

Comment: The first two points here don't really make sense
(1) overuse of a special case pattern is really the dev's fault.  it's like saying you should never use a global ref or static function even though on rare occasions there's good reasons to do so (e.g., global logger & extension methods)
(2) it doesn't make testing hard since you can inject the GlobalScope as a default value into the constructor. e.g., class MyApplication(val scope = GlobalScope()).  you invoke the alternative constructor during test time.  this is a pattern documented by google in their docs somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the existing answers, I came up with this solution:

```kotlin
class YourApplication : Application() {

    companion object {
        var applicationScope = MainScope()
    }
    
    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        applicationScope.cancel("onLowMemory() called by system")
        applicationScope = MainScope()
    }
}
```

The onLowMemory() part is somewhat optional, but seems a good idea, since unfinished jobs could sit there for the lifetime of your application and use system resources.

We don’t need to cancel this scope in `onDestroy` since we want it to remain active as long as the application process is alive, as stated in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution could be to use the `lifecycleScope` of [`ProcessLifecycleOwner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ProcessLifecycleOwner):

```
class YourApplication : Application() {
    ...
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        with(ProcessLifecycleOwner.get()) {
            lifecycle.addObserver(yourProcessLifeCycleObserver)
            lifecycleScope.launch { TODO("Do some work here.") }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#kts) for the necessary dependencies.

Comment: thank you. Can we use `lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle() { }` instead of `lifecycle.addObserver(yourProcessLifeCycleObserver)`?

Comment: That line is there for context as you would normally use `ProcessLifecycleOwner` to add a lifecycle observer, but you can omit it if you don't need one. Considering this runs in the application context, I don't think `repeatOnLifecycle` will have any effect, the application object is always present until the process is terminated.

Answer (score 2):

**GlobalScope** will be suitable for Application instance.The *get(*) method of taskRepository variable will work as **Provider Pattern**. It shouldn't be in app instance. It can be replace with **lazy** method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onLowMemory()` to release the CoroutineScope() on application class. `onLowMemory()` is similar to `onDestroy()`

```
val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main)
```

clear the scope

```
override fun onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory()
    applicationScope.cancel()
}
```

onLowMemory method to release any caches or other unnecessary resources you may be holding on to, The system will perform a garbage collection for you after returning from this method.

Comment: I think you don't need to call this method. If you add a breakpoint, it doesn't stop in the method. And if the app is being killed, the memory will be released soon.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to cancel pending jobs in `onLowMemory`, however the applicationScope won't accept any new jobs, which means launch won't work. You probably should create a fresh scope there too: `applicationScope = MainScope()`