# Which coroutine scope should I use in android.app.Application?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I need to call a suspend function in the on `onCreate` method of `android.app.Application`. Which coroutine scope should I use for that and why?

Comment: Do you need it to be cancelable, and if so, under what conditions?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I don't need it cancelable. I just want to start it and let it run until it's finished (by `await`ing it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coroutine scope on Application class android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61255807/coroutine-scope-on-application-class-android)

Answer (score 3):

You can either use `GlobalScope` or create your own scope in the Application class.

`GlobalScope` is not bound to a lifecycle event, and that's what you'd want to use in the Application class.

Answer (score 1):

By using `SupervisorJob()` you can cancel the Global scope when the application class gets destroyed

Sample code

```
val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Main)

applicationScope.launch {
 // action done in here
}

override fun onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory()
    applicationScope.cancel()
}
```

`onLowMemory()` is similar to `onDestroy()` fun in application class